# Data throughput measurement

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, internet-connection

I have a *Wifi router* and *10 laptops* connected to it.

I want to download a document in one of the laptops and measure the data throughput.

I also want to measure the data throughput when two or more laptops connected are downloading  at the same time.

Please how do I go about it ?

Comment: Linux Live CD and iperf is one way.

Comment: What data throughput? I has to come from somewhere or go somewhere. Do you want to measure WiFi-to-LAN performance? Or your Internet uplink’s?

Comment: Yes I want to measure from WiFi to LAN performance

Answer (score 1):

You can employ a tool called `iperf`.

You've not mentioned an OS, so:

- For Linux, the package / source should be readily available - look for `iperf3` (use the same link as below if necessary...)
- For Windows binaries are available here: https://iperf.fr/iperf-download.php

Use one of the laptops as the 'server':

```bsh
iperf3 -s -i 2
```

Use one or more as the 'clients':

```bsh
iperf3 -c ${HOSTNAME} -i 2
```

Replace `${HOSTNAME}` with the server's IP or hostname.

`-i ${SECONDS}` will show you a summary every *n* seconds

---

Transferring "*a document*" is unlikely to take long enough to be used as a decent metric.

Also, be aware that you should not use the internet as a component in the measurement unless your internet connection's performance is of interest - use devices on the local network.

If you are indeed interested in the internet bandwidth, then there are plenty of `iperf3` servers, see here: [here](https://iperf.fr/iperf-servers.php) or [google](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=public%20iperf%20server).

Comment: Thnks a lot but internet connection performance is of interest

Comment: @stellamarris please see my updated answer (there are public `iperf` servers that you can run clients against)

Comment: @Stellamarris Wifi to LAN implies a WiFi device to Wired Ethernet device (nothing to do with internet)

Comment: I want to show that the throughput of downloading a large file  from internet degrades when many users are connected to a wifi spot.pls how do I go about it

Comment: throughput of *what*? WiFi bandwidth between WiFi clients, or Internet bandwidth shared by clients on the local network?

Comment: WiFi bandwidth between WiFi clients

Comment: WiFi bandwidth between WiFi clients